# Decouple account and user service

Tags: node.js, express, architecture, microservices

Im trying to decouple these 2, account and user service.

On user register, the user enters in their account information (business name, tax number etc) + user information (profile settings etc).

Im wondering what is the best approach to decouple these two services on signup to get the one form submission to be stored in these 2 services?

Currently i have a setup, where when a user registers, it sends a post request to the auth service where, the auth service fires a webhook to account and user service.

I feel like this is prone to errors and might not be the standard approach.

I’d like to know how to properly do this - i.e how does netflix, google etc do this

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mechanism for implementing transactions that spans multiple microservices. In this case, the microservice architecture suggests using the [SAGA design pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) with compensating transactions.

[SAGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction) is actually a sequence of transactions for a set of microservices. Each transaction updates each microservice, which updates its own database and publishes a message or event to start the next transaction in the saga to update the next microservice. If such a transaction fails in any microservice, then SAGA performs a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes made by previous transactions.

SAGA are divided into 2 types:

1. Choreography - each transaction publishes events that trigger transactions in other microservices in turn (without an orchestrator).
2. Orchestration - there is a separate orchestrator that manages transactions and tells the participants what transactions need to be performed.

You should also keep in mind that when you add such a pattern to the architecture, the complexity of the architecture increases significantly, for more information about the problems and disadvantages, see the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga#issues-and-considerations).

More details can be found at links [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga) and [2](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

Comment: this is absolutely great, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Likely yes, the approach is correct, the service among the two which gets data directly from frontend has the responsibility of sending an asynchronous event to the other service so that it can also mutate the data in it's database and data consistency remains maintained, i.e. paradigm of eventual consistency itself.

Only the thing is that the message carriers/ brokers should be highly available.